# php- why traversing multidimensional array inside the foreach() doesnt work

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I"m trying to traverse on an object i"m getting from openweather.com

without the foreach() i"m getting the right result. inside the foreach() i get an error.

the php code:

```
 $contents = file_get_contents($url); 
 $clima=json_decode($contents,TRUE);

 echo $clima['list'][5]['main']['temp'];  // this one works

 $i=0;
 foreach($clima['list'] as $clima1) {
     echo $clima1[$i]['dt'];   // here i get PHP Notice:  Undefined offset

     echo $clima1[$i]['main']['temp']; //here i get PHP Notice:  Undefined index: list

     $i=$i+1;
 }
```

the error that i get is:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0   // the error is from 0 to 39 and there are 39 objects...
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: list
```

the object beginning and ending part for sample:

```
Array ( [cod] => 200 [message] => 0.014 [cnt] => 40 [list] => 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [dt] => 1492732800 [main] => Array ( [temp] => 17.64 [temp_min] => 17.04 [temp_max] => 17.64 [pressure] => 1026.03 [sea_level] => 1031.21 [grnd_level] => 1026.03 [humidity] => 100 [temp_kf] => 0.6 ) [weather] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 800 [main] => Clear [description] => clear sky [icon] => 01n ) ) [clouds] => Array ( [all] => 0 ) [wind] => Array ( [speed] => 1.66 [deg] => 81.5008 ) [sys] => Array ( [pod] => n ) [dt_txt] => 2017-04-21 00:00:00 ) 
        [38] => Array ( [dt] => 1493143200 [main] => Array ( [temp] => 19.72 [temp_min] => 19.72 [temp_max] => 19.72 [pressure] => 1026.92 [sea_level] => 1032.02 [grnd_level] => 1026.92 [humidity] => 87 [temp_kf] => 0 ) [weather] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 800 [main] => Clear [description] => clear sky [icon] => 01n ) ) [clouds] => Array ( [all] => 0 ) [wind] => Array ( [speed] => 6.95 [deg] => 10.5008 ) [sys] => Array ( [pod] => n ) [dt_txt] => 2017-04-25 18:00:00 ) 
         [39] => Array ( [dt] => 1493154000 [main] => Array ( [temp] => 18.43 [temp_min] => 18.43 [temp_max] => 18.43 [pressure] => 1026.75 [sea_level] => 1031.91 [grnd_level] => 1026.75 [humidity] => 98 [temp_kf] => 0 ) [weather] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 800 [main] => Clear [description] => clear sky [icon] => 01n ) ) [clouds] => Array ( [all] => 0 ) [wind] => Array ( [speed] => 6.03 [deg] => 9.50076 ) [sys] => Array ( [pod] => n ) [dt_txt] => 2017-04-25 21:00:00 ) ) 
 [city] => Array ( [id] => **** [name] => ***** [coord] => Array ( [lat] => **.**** [lon] => **.**** ) [country] => ** ) )
```

any help to understand my mistake will be appreciated

Comment: `$clima1['dt']` and `$clima1['main']['temp']`. Why did you even add `$i` there?

Comment: just remove `[$i]` ?

Comment: i misunderstood the output of var_dump. i removed the [$1] and now it's ok. thanks, all 3 answers helped me understand my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you loop "double". The counter inside the loop is the part, which you don't need, as you already loop over the array with foreach.

I think, the following  code would be the better approach

```
 $contents = file_get_contents($url); 
 $clima=json_decode($contents,TRUE);

 echo $clima['list'][5]['main']['temp'];  // this one works

 foreach($clima['list'] as $clima1) {
     echo $clima1['dt'];   // here i get PHP Notice:  Undefined offset

     echo $clima1['main']['temp']; //here i get PHP Notice:  Undefined index: list
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you foreach over `$clima['list']` you will get every values inside $clima['list']. Therefore, first, `$clima1 = $clima['list'][0]`. After that, `$clima1 = $clima['list'][1]`... Thus, $clima1 has neither 0 as an index nor 1 nor 2...

What you might do to see it more clearly is this :

```
foreach($clima['list'] as $key => $clima1)
```

And everytime, the $key will be your $id. Therefore, you can get rid of your $id and just do it like this :

```
foreach($clima['list'] as $id => $clima1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `foreach($clima['list'] as $clima1) { ...` each object in the loop (`$clima1`) is equal to `$clima['list'][$i]` so you don't need to manually put the `$i` in there.

If your really stuck I'd just run the loop like:

```
foreach($clima['list'] as $clima1) {
    var_dump('<pre>' . $clima1 . '</pre>');
}
```

To see what the `$clima1` variable really is.